# Why does the monitoring data obtained through rest API need to be updated every 6 to 10 seconds?

Tags: apache-flink

On the Web UI page, we can see that the relevant data is updated every 3S, such as the read-bytes of each operator.

But when I get data through Rest API, the data is updated every 6 seconds or even more than 10 seconds. Why?

The related data of read bytes obtained through Rest API is as follows:

19:02:04                  0              0              0              0              0              0              0

19:02:07                  0              0              0              0              0              0              0

19:02:10                  0              0              0              0              0              0              0

19:02:13                  0              0              0              0              0              0              0

19:02:16             792820         807792         684683         796474         813133         680141         689590

19:02:19             792820         807792         684683         796474         813133         680141         689590

19:02:22             792820         807792         684683         796474         813133         680141         689590

19:02:26             792820         807792         684683         796474         813133         680141         689590

19:02:29            1817569        1815899        1560744        1808234        1836741        1559341        1568711

19:02:32            1817569        1815899        1560744        1808234        1836741        1559341        1568711

19:02:35            1817569        1815899        1560744        1808234        1836741        1559341        1568711

19:02:38            1817569        1815899        1560744        1808234        1836741        1559341        1568711

19:02:41            2796433        2805973        2401927        2797311        2838168        2397542        2417726

19:02:45            2796433        2805973        2401927        2797311        2838168        2397542        2417726

19:02:48            2796433        2805973        2401927        2797311        2838168        2397542        2417726

19:02:51            3649398        3640050        3130583        3624854        3687889        3122333        3144306

19:02:54            3649398        3640050        3130583        3624854        3687889        3122333        3144306

19:02:57            3649398        3640050        3130583        3624854        3687889        3122333        3144306

19:03:00            3649398        3640050        3130583        3624854        3687889        3122333        3144306

19:03:03            4529443        4524218        3881509        4517926        4582770        3884389        3907298

19:03:06            4529443        4524218        3881509        4517926        4582770        3884389        3907298

19:03:09            4529443        4524218        3881509        4517926        4582770        3884389        3907298

19:03:12            5432212        5423566        4659737        5404419        5492786        4649469        4685430

19:03:16            5432212        5423566        4659737        5404419        5492786        4649469        4685430

19:03:19            5432212        5423566        4659737        5404419        5492786        4649469        4685430

19:03:22            5432212        5423566        4659737        5404419        5492786        4649469        4685430

19:03:25            6255327        6243823        5367516        6236577        6321958        5360496        5396446

19:03:28            6255327        6243823        5367516        6236577        6321958        5360496        5396446

19:03:31            6255327        6243823        5367516        6236577        6321958        5360496        5396446

19:03:34            7207042        7203725        6184804        7178875        7286207        6172393        6212499

19:03:37            7207042        7203725        6184804        7178875        7286207        6172393        6212499

19:03:40            7207042        7203725        6184804        7178875        7286207        6172393        6212499

19:03:43            7207042        7203725        6184804        7178875        7286207        6172393        6212499

19:03:47            8064759        8048237        6918715        8034269        8144119        6912701        6957967

19:03:50            8064759        8048237        6918715        8034269        8144119        6912701        6957967

19:03:53            8064759        8048237        6918715        8034269        8144119        6912701        6957967

19:03:56            8903005        8895364        7636796        8880999        9004171        7628515        7684865

19:03:59            8903005        8895364        7636796        8880999        9004171        7628515        7684865

19:04:02            8903005        8895364        7636796        8880999        9004171        7628515        7684865

19:04:05            9764407        9746490        8375615        9721560        9864876        8364266        8420637

19:04:08            9764407        9746490        8375615        9721560        9864876        8364266        8420637

19:04:11            9764407        9746490        8375615        9721560        9864876        8364266        8420637

19:04:14            9764407        9746490        8375615        9721560        9864876        8364266        8420637

19:04:18           10643486       10622845        9124814       10611981       10756388        9123061        9181804

19:04:21           10643486       10622845        9124814       10611981       10756388        9123061        9181804

19:04:24           10643486       10622845        9124814       10611981       10756388        9123061        9181804

19:04:27           11572984       11551082        9927120       11526018       11693689        9912304        9984155

19:04:30           11572984       11551082        9927120       11526018       11693689        9912304        9984155

19:04:33           11572984       11551082        9927120       11526018       11693689        9912304        9984155

19:04:36           11572984       11551082        9927120       11526018       11693689        9912304        9984155

19:04:40           12589024       12563325       10794787       12554152       12720400       10793328       10857505

19:04:44           12589024       12563325       10794787       12554152       12720400       10793328       10857505

19:04:47           12589024       12563325       10794787       12554152       12720400       10793328       10857505

19:04:50           13429485       13407045       11523015       13381818       13570519       11505681       11579628

19:04:53           13429485       13407045       11523015       13381818       13570519       11505681       11579628

19:04:56           13429485       13407045       11523015       13381818       13570519       11505681       11579628

19:04:59           13429485       13407045       11523015       13381818       13570519       11505681       11579628

19:05:02           14341219       14310437       12302435       14295362       14485186       12292233       12371000

19:05:05           14341219       14310437       12302435       14295362       14485186       12292233       12371000

19:05:08           14341219       14310437       12302435       14295362       14485186       12292233       12371000

19:05:11           15200307       15184989       13044311       15159531       15365128       13026223       13118296

19:05:14           15200307       15184989       13044311       15159531       15365128       13026223       13118296

19:05:18           15200307       15184989       13044311       15159531       15365128       13026223       13118296

19:05:21           15200307       15184989       13044311       15159531       15365128       13026223       13118296

19:05:24           16067200       16035181       13785007       16008243       16230192       13765004       13859413

Comment: This was discussed and answered on the mailing list: http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/The-problem-of-getting-data-by-Rest-API-td43536.html

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the time in UI interface is updated every 3S, and other data is about 10s. Is there any way to change the update frequency of other data ?